# How to Extract text from Wikipedia Article using sparql in json format?

Tags: python, json, sparql, wikipedia, sparqlwrapper

I want to extract some text of Wikipedia as JSON, using SPARQL. The following query retrieves the text, but in HTML format.  How can I get the JSON output?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
from pprint import pprint 


sparqlwiki = SPARQLWrapper("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saket_Modi")

sparqlwiki.setReturnFormat(JSON)
resultswiki = sparqlwiki.query().convert()
from pprint import pprint
pprint(resultswiki)
```

[output of above code can be found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-KXCK1XBk7kTURxMWVmV0QzYjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the actual result that you get back?  You say that it's HTML, but what is the actual value?  I don't know what **pprint** does for you--what is the actual value of `resultswiki`?

Comment: How can you use SPARQL to query a Wikipedia HTML page? SPARQLWrapper expects a SPARQL endpoint URL. And what is the default query? I'm pretty sure that this does not work. What would be the magic behind using SPARQL on text?

Comment: Why are you sending query to  `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saket_Modi` ? Wouldn't running a sparql query against DBPEDIA make a lot more sense?